# Exponential Service Times when Minimum Service Time is Reasonable in Queuing Theory

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution, queueing

I asked this question on the Mathematics stack exchange site but I didn't get a response. If posting it here means it should be closed or migrated from there, is there a way that i can do that? Or can a moderator to it?

---

In many queuing models it is assumed that the service time follows an exponential distribution with parameter $\mu=1/\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the average rate of service. An example might be a bank teller who, on average, is able to service customers at a rate of 1 every 10 minutes.

This assumption is obviously unrealistic in some respects. For example, there is certainly a minimum service time under which a teller could never complete a service routine. However, the exponential distribution has no such lower bound (other than a service time of 0) and in fact seems to assume that these extremely low service times are the most likely outcome. How is it that exponential service times end up being a reasonable approximation when they seem to imply that very small service times are the most likely outcome (which seems unrealistic) and don't account for any sort of floor on what service times are capable of being achieved?

Comment: Just flag your post on the Math site for a moderator's attention, requesting that it be migrated.

Comment: If the (modelled) probability of a service time below the (actual) floor is very low the model can be good enough for government work; it's not relevant that the probability _density_ is higher there.

Comment: @Scortchi I understand what you mean - it can be a good approximation in the same way that the normal distribution can approximate test scores and other quantities that have finite ranges. I had in mind situations where the actual service times had an extremely long right tail and most of the times were occurring at the floor. I guess in light of your response it's fair to say that in that case an exponential distribution would just be a poor assumption to make.